# Getting the list of running user process in QNX

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx, xlet

I am running some daemon user processes as well as some Xlet GUI apps in a QNX operating system.I connect to the QNX console using TeraTerm.I need to get the list of running user apps/process inorder to see which user apps are already running in the system. I would be needing processID , memory & appname.

I came across the `pidin` command,but it list out all the process.Anyways to filter out user process and their app names ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would really like to have an better answer like 'use ps', but BB10 did not include this (at least we cannot access it so far as I know).
But furtunatly there is something that is at least a bit better than pidin:

```
hogs -n -i 1
```

-n stands for 'display process name', but I think you can omit it, because it is default(?)
-i <N> gives the number of iterations, this means '1' will only show it once. Omitting this option will continuously list this output all 3 seconds.

Output looks like this:

```
$ hogs -n -i 1            
  PID           NAME   MSEC PIDS  SYS       MEMORY
48095409       qconn      1   0%   0%    716k  49%
48111818        sshd      1   0%   0%    412k  28%
48328909        hogs      5   3%   0%    132k   9%
48111820         -sh     77  57%   2%    180k  12%
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try `pidin a`.

```
pidin a | grep 'name of your process you are looking for'
```

Comment: On QNX 7, `pidin a` no longer works:
`pidin: 'a' invalid or ambiguous shorthand`

Comment: @leosh running it without the `a` works for me